# Calculate the difference in minutes between 'First-row' and 'Second-row' with 2 different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in which I have to calculate the difference in minutes between 'First-row' **Emp_Out** and 'Second-row' **Emp_IN** for each room and for each day starting from 12 am.

**Table:**

```
Date        EMP_ID        Room       Emp_IN       Emp_OUT        Difference(In Min)
-----       ------        ------     ------       -------        ------------------
9/1/22      001           Room 1     04:30        05:00           270              (First diff is calulated from 12am - Emp_IN)
9/1/22      002           Room 1     05:25        05:42           7
9/1/22      003           Room 1     05:48        06:13           6
9/1/22      001           Room 2     05:00        05:17           300              (First diff is calulated from 12am - Emp_IN)
9/1/22      002           Room 2     05:36        05:48           19
9/1/22      003           Room 2     05:51        06:05           3
```

Can LAG be used for it or I'm missing a logic which can be helped?

Comment: Did lag work when you tried?

Comment: `LAG` is exactly what you want here, with `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: @DaleK I haven't tried LAG and can you help me out on it?

Comment: @Larnu Can you help me with the logic as I didn't get the correct way to apply it as I involves 2 diff rows and 2 diff columns

Comment: Read the documentation and have a go - you might surprise yourself. Lord of the rings has just been released here - so I won't be answering questions for a while lol

Comment: Also on each day and room for 1st row, 12 am should be added for calculation manually. just FYI.

Comment: `LAG` has a parameter for the value returned when there is no row.

Comment: @YenRuby, Hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LAG` to get the next row value, partition the rows using `Room`

The first entry of the day for the room will get `Null` and replace that with **'00:00'** which means **12 AM**.

```
SELECT *, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ISNULL(LAG(Emp_out) OVER(PARTITION BY Date, Room ORDER BY Emp_In),'00:00'),Emp_In) [Difference in Min]
FROM Your_table
```

My sample scripts and the result

```
create table #temp(empdate date, empId int, room varchar(100), InTime time, outTime time)

insert into #temp Values ('2022-09-02','101','Room 1','04:30','05:00')
insert into #temp Values ('2022-09-02','102','Room 1','05:25','05:42')
insert into #temp Values ('2022-09-02','103','Room 1','05:48','07:00')
insert into #temp Values ('2022-09-02','101','Room 2','05:00','05:17')
insert into #temp Values ('2022-09-02','102','Room 2','05:36','05:48')
insert into #temp Values ('2022-09-02','103','Room 2','05:51','06:00')

SELECT *, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ISNULL(LAG(outTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Room ORDER BY InTime),'00:00'),Intime) [Difference in Min]
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Output:**

```
empdate    empId       room       InTime           outTime          Difference in Min
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------------- ---------------- -----------------
2022-09-02 101         Room 1     04:30:00.0000000 05:00:00.0000000 270
2022-09-02 102         Room 1     05:25:00.0000000 05:42:00.0000000 25
2022-09-02 103         Room 1     05:48:00.0000000 07:00:00.0000000 6
2022-09-02 101         Room 2     05:00:00.0000000 05:17:00.0000000 300
2022-09-02 102         Room 2     05:36:00.0000000 05:48:00.0000000 19
2022-09-02 103         Room 2     05:51:00.0000000 06:00:00.0000000 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the table

```
CREATE TABLE DEMOLAG (Date Datetime , EMP_ID INT , Room Varchar(50), EMP_IN TIME(0) , EMP_OUT TIME(0))
```

Insert the Records

```
INSERT INTO DEMOLAG VALUES ('9/1/22',001,'ROOM 1', '04:30','05:00')
INSERT INTO DEMOLAG VALUES ('9/1/22',002,'ROOM 1', '05:25','05:42')
INSERT INTO DEMOLAG VALUES ('9/1/22',003,'ROOM 1', '05:48','06:13')
INSERT INTO DEMOLAG VALUES ('9/1/22',001,'ROOM 2', '05:00','05:17')
INSERT INTO DEMOLAG VALUES ('9/1/22',002,'ROOM 2', '05:36','05:48')
INSERT INTO DEMOLAG VALUES ('9/1/22',003,'ROOM 2', '05:51','06:05')
```

USE LEG Function to achieve

```
    SELECT *,
    ISNULL((LAG(EMP_OUT,1) OVER(Partition by Room ORDER BY EMP_OUT,Room,Emp_ID ASC)),'00:00') AS Prvempout, 
    DATEDIFF(Minute,ISNULL((LAG(EMP_OUT,1) OVER(Partition by Room ORDER BY EMP_OUT,Room,Emp_ID ASC)),'00:00'),EMP_IN) AS Timediff 
    FROM DEMOLAG
```

For more detail explanation you can refer to [Use LAG Function in SQL](https://youtu.be/AtmJbwfJtyY)